# ¿How can generate a json response without a sql query?

Tags: php

I want to generate a this type of json:

```
{
    "message": [
        [
            "message":"ok"
        ]
    ]
}
```

, but im trying to do this without a sql query only using php only can do that of this way :

```
{
    "message": [
        [
            "ok"
        ]
    ]
}
```

My code its the next...

```
$respuesta["message"] = array();
if (mail($to,  utf8_decode($subject), utf8_decode($message), $header)) {
    $tmp = array();
    $tmp=["ok"];
    array_push($respuesta["message"], $tmp);
    echo json_encode($respuesta);
} else {
    $tmp = array();
    $tmp=["no"];
    array_push($respuesta["message"], $tmp);
    echo json_encode($respuesta);
}
```

Comment: Learn PHP. [Associative array syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) `['key' => 'value']` e.g. `array_push($respuesta["message"], ['message' => $tmp]);`

Comment: Your JSON `[ "message":"ok" ]` is invalid. Should be curly braces `{}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code generating an associative PHP array (translated into objects in JSON) can be written in short using the ternary operator `CONDITION ? ON_TRUE : ON_FALSE`

```
$respuesta["message"] = [];
array_push($respuesta["message"], ['message' => mail($to, utf8_decode($subject), utf8_decode($message), $header) ? 'ok':'no']);
echo json_encode($respuesta);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can try stdClass

```
$r = new stdClass();
$r->message = array();

$ms = new stdClass();
$ms->message="ok";
array_push($r->message,$ms);
 echo json_encode($r);
```